# How to read this mathematics value: 10^9

Tags: mathematics, reading-aloud

I have this value

[image: N = 10^9 (9 in superscript)]

How to read that in English? translating from my native language, I would say

> Ten base of nine.

but is that really correct?

Comment: Ten to the power of nine. Ten raised to the ninth power. Ten to the ninth power.

Comment: This question touched on the topic of scientific notation:  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48494

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Formally it is

*Ten to the power of nine*

but more commonly:

*Ten to the nine* or *Ten to the ninth*

The use of *Base 9* has a very different meaning.

Comment: Or, in this specific case, "one billion".

Comment: Or, if you're old-school British, a milliard. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,000,000,000

Comment: If you're as old school British as I am, the word would be Gillion.  You don't hear that much nowadays.