# How to pronounce this character `^`

Tags: pronunciation, reading-aloud

this character `^` could be typed by shift + 6, usually means powers of some number, the question is

How to pronounce this character `^`?

Comment: This character can stand for different meanings or have different names, but I wouldn't say it has a pronunciation. [The wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) lists several names for this symbol.

Comment: Related questions:  "[What do programmers call these punctuation marks? (Parentheses, brackets, ticks, etc.)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108169)" and "[How to read this mathematics value: 10^9](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51803)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @katatahito pointed out that character has [multiple meanings depending on the context.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret)

On its own that character is called the "caret". Not to be confused with "carrot" the vegetable or "carat" the unit of measure.

However its most common use is in mathematics and is used to represent the [exponential operation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation). In this case you would usually pronounce it "<number> to the <number> power" or "<number> to the <number>".

So 2^5 would be read as either "two to the fifth power" or "two to the fifth".

Comment: I suggest In this case you would usually pronounce it " to the power" should be replaced with "In this case you would usually refer to it as " to the power""

Comment: Possibly UkE, but we also express this as *2 to the power **of** 5*

Comment: It is mostly a caret or a tilde. That is how you **say it**.

Comment: It is also the XOR operator in some languages, including C. Its **not a tilde** the tilde is the character ~ .  The character ^ is a caret and not a tilde.

Answer (score 2):

**How to pronounce this character `^`**

Firstly I think we should define what a **character** is as there seems to be some confusion in the comments associated with this post. A character is a **letter number or symbol** used in writing. However not all characters have associated sounds. **In English the characters associated with sounds are called letters.**

In English, There is no pronunciation for `^` as it is not a letter. As such it will have a name or in this case several names. (I will not list them as it has already been linked in comments and is not directly relevant to this question and associated answer).

It is irrelevant if it is a caret or a tilde **The answer to the question is you cannot pronounce it. Only letters can be pronounced in the English Language. 1 Cannot be pronounced but "o-n-e" can be.**

Note; There are 26 letters in the English alphabet.

**character**; noun: It is a **letter, number, or other symbol** used in writing, especially in printed text or on a computer:[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/character)

**letter**; noun: any of the set of symbols used to write a language, in many languages, representing a sound in the language:[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/letter)