# When you say 1,001,000, do you include 'and'?

Tags: numbers

Which is better, ***one million and one thousand*** or ***one million one thousand***?
Or, do you use both?

Is there any difference BE and AE regarding this?

Comment: no and, any English

Comment: A similar question was raised in the past. Refer to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48494/how-to-read-numbers-in-english

Answer (score 1):

"And" is only used after the hundreds  (three hundred and twenty-five). Quite a few Americans will say three hundred twenty-five, especially in formal settings, because we had it drilled into our heads as children that **and** indicated the decimal. In practical terms this only ever mattered when writing a check/cheque, and it usually goes unnoticed in speech,

Otherwise there are no "and"s  : "one million, one thousand."

(If you need to actually use this number once in your lifetime you have been very lucky)

Comment: I think that the rule of not to saying *and* has several reasons. A more important one may be that "one hundred and one" parses differently from "one hundred and one half". It also cleans much of the mess of the vernacular, which is neither consistent or stable. Consider ["a million and one"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+million+and+one+(something)), Also see [usage patterns](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2019&content=million+one%2Cmillion+and+one&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Comment: Two Thousand and One, A Space Odyssey? One Thousand and One Arabian Nights?

Comment: Someone might say that years are a special case, as "twenty twenty" for 2020, but the other examples are sound. I think the rule that @JamesK may intend to express is that any occurrence of the word *and* should occur between the 100's and 10's places. That is, the words following *and* should describe the last (least significant) two digits of the whole part of the number. In the case of 100,001, the last two digits are said as "one", so the entire number is said as "one million *and* one".